# PIC24 Breakpoint on Either Read Or Write Memory Access

Tags: embedded, pic, mplab, pic24

My environment...

- PIC24
- MpLab (V.8.80)
- ICD 3

I have a byte that I want to watch, to see which routines are reading and which ones are actually writing, and when it happens

I can only set a breakpoint on

- when the byte is written, or
- when it is read

Does anyone know a way that I can set a breakpoint on either access ? i.e., I would like to watch what is written, AND what is read, in what order, by which instruction, in which routine.

All I have are a PICkit 3 and this ICD-3. It's a dual processor system where the two chips are communicating via some wires connected (ultimately, via Peripheral Pin Select) to their respective UARTs

I have never used, or touched, or even seen, a REAL Ice. Would that allow me to do this ? i.e., any bus memory access.

This is what MpLab lets me do right now with ICD-3
[image]

Comment: Can't you set two breakpoints, one for each of "read" and "write"?

Comment: No, when I try what you suggest, I get a MessageBox, `There is already a break point set for address NNNN`

Comment: even with "advanced breakpoints"?

Comment: I don't think I have "advanced breakpoints". I edited my original post to include a screen cap of the options which MpLab here provides in memory breakpoints.

Comment: Do you have the source-code of your routines? If yes, you can use eclipse to achieve this: Ctrl+Alt+H on a variable will show you what functions read and write to a variable. Try it by simply copying your code to a new eclipse project (make sure indexing is enabled).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to watch and see if one routine reads the value before the other has written to it; i.e., if the protocol is executing in proper order

Answer (score 0):

Can you enclose your variable in a functions as below into a new .c file. set the define on the header file.

It might be a bit heavy but with a replace it could help. **FILE** and **LINE** are compiler flags to let you know from which file on the source code and at which line it is called. The Nop(); is there because the interrupt can happen few instruction late.

Add a watch on file and line to see where it's called from.

```
#define setvar(x) zsetvar(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define getvar() zgetvar( __FILE__, __LINE__)


byte my_var;

void zsetvar(byte val, volatile char * file, volatile char * line)
{
 my_var = val;// set breakpoint
 Nop(); 
}
byte zreadvar(volatile char * file, volatile char * line)
{
 Nop(); //set breakpoint
 Nop();
 return my_var;
}
```